# Theming a custom menu block in Drupal 7

Tags: routes, theming

So I created a custom menu through the Drupal administration and named it "More Menu." Its machine name, *menu-more-menu*, was auto-generated by Drupal.

Creating this menu automatically created its corresponding block, and its now available under Blocks administration as More Menu. I then enabled the block and placed it under my desired Region.

I wanted to theme the output of this block. I tried creating a template by following the template suggestion as described [here](http://drupal.org/node/1089656), block--*module*--*delta*.tpl.php.

The template file I created was named block--*menu*--*menu-more-menu*.tpl.php.

It doesn't seem to work, and I still cannot override it.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

For custom menu blocks the format for the block template file name is

```
block--menu--<menu_machine_name>.tpl.php
```

**Note**: All machine names begin with the 'menu_' prefix and all hyphens are converted to underscores.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the heck of it, can you try assigning the actual ID of the block in place of 'menu-more-menu'?  So you'd end up with something like block--menu--23.tpl.php.  It's just to prove to ourselves that the template system is in fact working and that something is running afoul with the name you're using.

Comment: I tried using its bid, but still not working.

Comment: How did you create the template file?

Comment: I just found out its a known issue.  http://drupal.org/node/1021270 Anyway, what i did is I copied an existing block.tpl.php and renamed it as instructed. I placed on on my appropriate theme folder.

Comment: I got it working though, block template should be: block--menu--menu_more_menu.tpl.php

Comment: Excellent.  That's a serious DrupalWTF.  Glad it's working.